# Section numbering and package "sectsty" together with "titlesec"

Tags: fonts, titlesec, sectsty

I use both packages. However, if I load `sectsty` before `titlesec` the section numbering of a subsubsection ends with 1.1, but has to 1.1.1. 
And if I load `titlesec` before `sectsty`, subsubsection numbering works fine but I can't use different font colors and font faces for the section headings.

Are both packages incompatible?
If so, what else can I do?

Thanks for any tips
The-OMH

Comment: Hi @The OMH. Would you please provide a minimal working example (MWE) so that we can check your problem?

Comment: The simple answer is don't use the two packages together, since they are not really compatible. If you need the power of `titlesec` then use it for everything.  Here's an example of doing that with `titlesec` [Change section fonts](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/10138). It uses XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX because of the fonts being chosen, but can easily be adapted to pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I cleared up my tex file. Now it works :-)